# Moduli of smooth curves in $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1}(2,2)| $ and their invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory, classical-invariant-theory

It is well known that any smooth curve 
$C\in |\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^1\times\mathbf{P}^1}(2,2)| $ has geometric genus equal to 1, so its isomorphism class is determined by its $j$-invariant. Nevertheless we have that $\dim(\mathbf P(H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^1\times\mathbf{P}^1}(2,2))))=8$ and $\dim(\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf P^1\times\mathbf P^1))=6$. So the dimension of the GIT quotient
$$
\mathbf P(H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^1\times\mathbf{P}^1}(2,2)))//\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf P^1\times\mathbf P^1)
$$
is 2. If we assume that the base field has characteristic 0, then by Castelnuovo theorem the quotient above is a rational surface. So, at least for a dense subset, there should be two numbers $I_1,I_2$ parametrizing the orbits of the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf P^1\times\mathbf P^1)$.

My questions are:

1) Are these numbers known (in terms of the coefficients of the defining polynomial of $C$)?

2) How are they related to the $j$-invariant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Geometrically we can see not just a $j$-invariant but also
a divisor class on Jac$(C)$, coming from the difference of the
degree-$2$ classes ${\mathcal O}(1,0)$ and ${\mathcal O}(0,1)$.
Conversely, given a genus-$1$ curve $C$ and two degree-$2$ divisors $D_1,D_2$
you can recover the embedding $\iota: C \to {\bf P}^1 \times {\bf P}^1$ from
the two degree-$2$ maps $f_i : C \to {\bf P}^1$ obtained from sections of $D_i$.
$$ $$
Somebody else will probably post a description or reference to the
invariant theory of $(2,2)$ forms before I have the chance to
work it out or look it up.

Comment: I added the tag "classical invariant theory" which is the one most relevant to the question, I think. That's because what is asked is to figure out some explicit generators for the ring of invariants of bihomogeneous forms $F(x,y)$ of bidegree $(2,2)$ in $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ under the group $SL_2\times SL_2$. I suspect one should be able to construct three explicit invariants $J_1,J_2,J_3$ and take for $I_1$ and $I_2$ suitable ratios of powers of these invariants to make them absolute.

Comment: There is a single (up to scale) invariant $J_1$ in degree two, and $J_2$ in degree three. I still have to think about $J_3$.

Comment: If $G(x)$ is a binary quartic in $x=(x_1,x_2)$, one can define a biform $F$ by polarizing twice, i.e., applying $(y\cdot\partial_x)^2$ to $G$. Pulling back a $SL_2\times SL_2$ invariant of the resulting biform $F(x,y)$ gives an $SL_2$ invariant of $G$. This could help in finding the connection to $j$ invariants of elliptic curves.

Comment: The ring of invariants is ${\bf C}[J_2,J_3,J_4]$ where
$J_k$ (each $k=2,3,4$) is a polynomial invariant of degree $k$.
The Jacobian of $C$ is $y^2 = x (x-J_2)^2 - 4 J_4 x + J_3^2$,
with a visible rational point $(x,y) = (0,J_3)$.
This must be classical but it's more fun to work it out than to
try to hunt it down in the literature.  I'll post one approach soon.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I guess it makes more sense to index the $J$'s by their degree...:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**EDITED** to exhibit $j$ as a rational function of $J_2,J_3,J_4$,
and to fix various local errors etc.]

The action of ${\rm SL_2} \times {\rm SL_2}$ on the $9$-dimensional space of
$(2,2)$ forms has a polynomial ring of invariants, with generators in degrees
$2,3,4$.  If we write a general $(2,2)$ form $P(x_1,x_2;y_1,y_2)$ as
$(x_1^2, x_1 x_2, x_2^2) M_3 (y_1^2, y_1 y_2, y_2^2)^{\sf T}$ where
$M_3$ is the $3 \times 3$ matrix
$$
M_3 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{00} & a_{01} & a_{02} \cr
 a_{10} & a_{11} & a_{12} \cr
 a_{20} & a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array} \right) \; ,
$$
then $J_k$ ($k=2,3,4$) can be taken to be the $x^{4-k}$ coefficient of the
characteristic polynomial $\chi^{\phantom.}_{M_4}$ of the $4 \times 4$ matrix
$$
M_4 = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac12 a_{11} & -a_{10} & -a_{01} & 2 a_{00} \cr
   a_{12} & -\frac12 a_{11} & -2 a_{02} & a_{01} \cr
   a_{21} & -2 a_{20} & -\frac12 a_{11} & a_{10} \cr
 2 a_{22} & -a_{21} & -a_{12} & \frac12 a_{11}
\end{array} \right) .
$$
This matrix is characterized by the identity
$$
P(x_1,x_2;y_1,y_2) =
(z_{11},z_{12},z_{21},z_{22}) M_4 (z_{22},-z_{21},-z_{12},z_{11})^{\sf T}
$$
where each $z_{ij} = x_i y_j$, together with the requirement that
$M_4$ has trace zero and becomes symmetric when its columns are listed
in reverse order and columns $2,3$ are multiplied by $-1$.
The invariants of degree $2$ and $3$ can also be written as
$$
J_2 = -\frac12 a_{11}^2 + 2(a_{01} a_{21} + a_{10} a_{12})
- 4 (a_{00} a_{22} + a_{20} a_{02}),
\quad
J_3 = -4 \det M_3;
$$
of course $J_4 = \det M_4$.
The (Jacobian of the) genus-$1$ curve $P=0$ is isomorphic with the
elliptic curve
$$
y^2 = x (x-J_2)^2 - 4 J_4 x + J_3^2.
$$
In particular this lets us compute the $j$-invariant of this curve
as a rational function of $J_2,J_3,J_4$:
$$
j = \frac{256 (J_2^2 + 12 J_4)^3}{16 J_2^4 J_4 - 4 J_2^3 J_3^2
   - 128 J_2^2 J_4^2 + 144 J_2 J_3^2 J_4 + 256 J_4^3 - 27 J_3^4} \, .
$$

One way to obtain these results is as follows.  First compute the
Hilbert series of the invariant ring.  We find that it is
$1 / \bigl( (1-t^2) (1-t^3) (1-t^4) \bigr)$; this suggests
a polynomial ring of invariants with generators of degrees $2,3,4$,
and shows that if we find independent invariants $J_2,J_3,J_4$
of those degrees then ${\bf C}[J_2,J_3,J_4]$ is the full invariant ring.

Now use the basis $\{z_{ij}\}$ of the four-dimensional space,
call it $Z$, of sections of ${\cal O}(1,1)$; it is well-known that
$\{z_{ij}\}$ embeds ${\bf P}^1 \times {\bf P}^1$ into ${\bf P}^3$
as the quadric $z_{11} z_{22} = z_{12} z_{21}$,
identifying ${\rm SL_2} \times {\rm SL_2}$ with
the special orthogonal group ${\rm SO}(Q)$ where
$Q$ is the quadratic form $z_{11} z_{22} - z_{12} z_{21}$.
This identifies $P$ with some other quadratic form $\tilde P$
in the $z_{ij}$, determined uniquely modulo ${\bf C} Q$.

Now $Q$ is nondegenerate, so it identifies $Z$ with its dual $Z^*$,
and thus identifies quadratic forms on $Z$ with self-adjoint maps
$T: Z \to Z$, with $Q$ itself mapping to the identity map.
It is known that generically ${\rm SO}(q)$ orbits of such $T$
are determined by their spectrum, and thus by the characteristic polynomial
$\chi^{\phantom.}_T$.  There is a unique translate $\tilde P + cQ$ of trace zero,
represented by the above matrix $M_4$.  Hence the coefficients
$J_2,J_3,J_4$ of $\chi^{\phantom.}_{M_4}$ are invariant and independent,
as claimed.

To identify the elliptic curve, write $C$ as a double cover of
one of the ${\bf P}^1$'s by taking the discriminant of $P$ with respect to
the other ${\bf P}^1$, and then use classical formulas for the
Jacobian of a genus-$1$ curve $y^2 = {\rm quartic}$.
The formulas, though not pretty to look at, are short enough
to let us identify the coefficients with polynomials in $J_2,J_3,J_4$.
The resulting curve has a rational point whose $x$-coordinate is
a multiple of $J_2$; translating $x$ to put this point at $x=0$
yields the model $y^2 = x (x-J_2)^2 - 4 J_4 x + J_3^2$ exhibited above.
The visible rational point $(x,y) = (0,J_3)$
ought to correspond to the difference between the divisors
${\mathcal O(0,1)}_C$ and ${\mathcal O(1,0)}_C$,
but I haven't checked this.

Comment: Nice answer. Does my polarization argument in my comments above help at all with the $j$ invariant question? It seems to provide an embedding of the moduli space of elliptic curves inside the OP's moduli space, but I don't know if the two ways computing $j$ coincide on this locus.

Comment: I'm not sure.  
(In any case the natural map goes the other way,
from the moduli of $(2,2)$ curves to moduli of elliptic curves.)
I did use the invariant theory of binary quartics
to write the elliptic curve in terms of $J_2,J_3,J_4$.
The $j$-invariant can be computed from my answer -- e.g. **ellinit([0,-2*J2,0,J2^2-4*J4,J3^2]).j** in gp --
though inevitably it's not very pretty.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam The composition of your map with Noam's is quadratic - it sends a binary quartic $f$ to $ (d^2f /dx_1^1) (d^2 f/dx_2^2) - (d^2 f/dx_1 dx_2)^2$, I think - so it shouldn't preserve the $j$ invariant.

Comment: @WillSawin: my map is linear it sends the binary quartic $f(x_1,x_2)$ to $D^2 f$ where $D$ is the differential operator $y_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+y_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$. The result is a biform in $x$ and $y$ of bidegree $(2,2)$. What you wrote sounds more like the Hessian of $f$ which is another binary quartic. Sorry if my notations were confusing.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Sorry, I should have been more clear. There are actually two maps from biforms of bidegree $(2,2)$ to binary quartics which preserve the $j$ invariant. These are given by taking the discriminant in one of the two variables. They were mentioned as the "natural map" by Noam. To see what your map does to the $j$ invariant, we can compose it with either of them. Doing this gives the Hessian. Thus your map preserves $j$ if and only if the Hessian does. (But it could still help somehow even if it does not preserve $j$.)

Comment: @WillSawin: Sorry I misread and missed the part about composition.